# Overlap multiple images at same position inside two different divs

Tags: css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="divFather" class="clsFather">
    <div class="clsSon">
        <img src="A.png">
        <img src="B.png">
    </div>
    <div class="clsSon">
        <img src="A.png">
        <img src="B.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the .css file:

```
.clsSon{
float: left;
width: 50%;
text-align: center;
position: relative;}

.clsSon img{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;}
```

With this, I am trying to have two divs in one row, with two overlaped images in each div.  But instead of that, I get four images overlaped in only one place.  I want to get 2 + 2 overlaped images in one row of two divs.  How can I get it?

Comment: Try out CSS positioning, `relative` + `absolute`

Comment: As you can check in my code, I am already using relative + absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```css
.clsSon {
  float: left;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.clsSon img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="divFather" class="clsFather">
    <div class="clsSon">
        <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/160x160">
        <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/160x160/?mountain">
    </div>
    <div class="clsSon">
        <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/160x160">
        <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/160x160/?mountain">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is near, but I would need to keep both divs centered inside the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to do it in this way:

```
.clsSon{
float: left;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
height: 160px;
width: 50%;}

.clsSon img{
position: absolute;
margin: auto;}
```